# Passing pointer to a pointer to a struct as a function parameter in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, parameter-passing

How do I pass a pointer to a pointer to a struct as a function parameter in C#?

I am trying to use a function from a DLL which has one of its arguments as a double pointer. For e.g.,

```
struct mystruct
{
   int a;
   char b;
};

[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
private static extern int func_name(int a, char b, mystruct** c);
```

I guess the correct way to use a pointer like `int *a` is `ref int a`. Is there anything similar for `int **a`?

Answer (score 2):

**The CLR equivalent for a pointer to a pointer is `ref IntPtr`.**

An [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) is a pointer to an integer, and when you pass it by `ref`, it's transferred by reference, making it a pointer to a pointer.

You may also need to use the [`Marshal.PtrToStructure` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) to convert the pointer to your structure object.

See the section entitled "Manual marshalling" near the bottom of [this article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would work differently.
Any pointer should be used as

> System.IntPtr

and I would then use

> Marshal.PtrToStructure

for the actual conversion of the pointer to actual structure. Otherwise I would also consider to copy field by field with offsets, which is sometimes easier to debug.